# React: API request on onClick or componentDidMount() lifecycle

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a doubt perhaps closer to "good practices" and performance than to the own functionality.
I have 2 components.

1. **ListPosts.js** (connected to Redux) and its route is: **/posts**
2. **Post.js** and its route is: **/posts/:id**

The first one list all the posts and if you click in a particular post, example post with id:6, you go to that route... /posts/6

Currently I´m grabbing the ID (in Post.js) through this.props.match.params.id making the API call on componentDidMount(){}

However I have a doubt... Is there other better way to do it...? Like, making the request when the user clicks on the link (on ListPosts.js) and passing down all the post data to the Post.js component.

I will appreciate advice. I´m trying to learn an improve the ways I´m working.
thanks

Comment: Please look into route redial. This might help you :)
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-redial

Comment: what if you go directly to `/posts/5` using the url? then you would have to use componentDidMount

Comment: @azium thanks... It is also working in that way. What I want to improve is performance. Maybe I can make the call in the list page and check in the particular one if data has been passed as props, and, if not make the call in this one in the proper lifecycle.